# How to set multiple FontStyles when instantiating a font?

Tags: c#, asp.net, system.drawing

In looking at the constructors for the System.Drawing.Font class there is a parameter to pass in one of the FontStyles defined in the System.Drawing.FontStyle enum.

ie. 
    Bold
    Italic
    Regular
    Underline

and there are boolean properties for Bold, Italic, Underline etc. in the instantiated object, but they are read only.

What if I want to define my font to have multiple styles like Bold and Underline?

How can I do this?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The `FontStyle` enum is a `Flags` enum. This means that its members are all powers of two, allowing you to combine them using a binary OR.

For example, if you want bold and underline, you'd pass

```
FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Underline
```

The vertical bar (`|`) is the binary OR operator.

Comment: Worked perfectly thank you! These kinds of things are new concepts to us Java junkies.

Answer (score 12):

In the Font constructor, you can combine multiple FontStyles using the OR operator:

```
Font font = new Font(this.Font, FontStyle.Bold | FontStyle.Underline);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this, in order to avoid multiple ifs for each case:

```
//define a font to use.
Font font;

font = new Font(fontname, fontsize, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

if (bold)
    font = new Font(font, font.Style ^ FontStyle.Bold);
if (italic)
    font = new Font(font, font.Style ^ FontStyle.Italic);
if (underline)
    font = new Font(font, font.Style ^ FontStyle.Underline);
if (strikeout)
    font = new Font(font, font.Style ^ FontStyle.Strikeout);
```

Comment: This is horribly inefficient...Use the flags enum to set multiple styles at once.