# Initialization Font Object with multiple style

Tags: c#

I need to initialize a font object with multiple style at runtime depending on four boolean values.

```
    bool bold,italic,underline,strikeout;

     myFont = new Font(fontText[0], size, FontStyle.Bold,FontStyle.Italic,FontStyle.Undeline,FontStyle.Strikeout);
//If all boolen values are true.
```

If all possibilities of boolen values are consider there will be 24 cases.

How can avoid writing all these condition?
Suggest some way do this ?

Comment: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813134/how-to-set-multiple-fontstyles-when-instantiating-a-font By the way, it's only 16 cases.

Comment: @Mr.Lister Font style may be completely absent so  4*3*2*1 = 24;

Comment: No, that's not correct, sorry. You can't combine font styles in more than one way. `FontStyle.Italic|FontStyle.Bold` is exactly the same as `FontStyle.Bold|FontStyle.Italic`. Does the question I linked to help?

Answer (score 0):

try this, I get answered :

```
Font myFont;
myFont = new Font(fontName, fontSize, FontStyle.Bold|FontStyle.Italic|FontStyle.Undeline|FontStyle.Strikeout);
```

for example :

```
Font myFont;
float fontSize=12;
string fontName="Arial";
bool bold=false,italic=false;
if(bold==true && italic==true)
myFont=new Font(fontName,fontSize,FontStyle.Bold|FontStyle.Italic);
```