# VB to C# translation of property to int cast

Tags: c#, vb.net, properties

original (works):

```
Dim fnt As Drawing.Font = New Drawing.Font( _
  rtf.SelectionFont.FontFamily, _
  rtf.SelectionFont.Size, _
  DirectCast(rtf.SelectionFont.Style _
  + If(rtf.SelectionFont.Underline, _
  -Drawing.FontStyle.Underline, _
  Drawing.FontStyle.Underline), _
  Drawing.FontStyle) _
)
```

translation ()cannot cast FontStyle to int:

```
System.Drawing.Font fnt = new System.Drawing.Font(
  rtf_Renamed.SelectionFont.FontFamily, 
  rtf_Renamed.SelectionFont.Size,
  (System.Drawing.FontStyle)(
    rtf_Renamed.SelectionFont.Style 
    + rtf_Renamed.SelectionFont.Underline 
    ? -System.Drawing.FontStyle.Underline  //cannot cast to int
    : System.Drawing.FontStyle.Underline
  )
);
```

So how to cast those .NET properties to their numerical values?

Comment: Your VB code is broken. Please **always** use `Option Strict On` and fix the resulting compile errors.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - Agreed this is 'broken' but this actually compiles with Option Strict On (assuming rtf is a RichTextBox control) although  the DirectCast was probably the suggested 'fix' by Visual Studio which is why it's there

Comment: Konrad Rudolph is right but, apparently, this is not the case here. The OP's code works fine because of a curious DirectCast behaviour I personally wasn't aware of.

Comment: @MattWilko I have done some tests and wrote the conclusions in my answer (comments): DirectCast has a different behaviour than normal cast in C# on this specific context, I didn't know anything about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe what your code is trying to do is add the underline if the original was not underlined, otherwise remove it.

But the [FontStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.fontstyle.aspx) should be bitmasked so that the underline part is toggled.
You should not be performing arithmetic addition and subtraction as this won't work well if the original style has any other attributes set.

The fact that you have to do a DirectCast is an alarm bell to say something may not be right.

You VB code should look like this:

```
Dim fnt As Drawing.Font = New Drawing.Font(rtf.SelectionFont.FontFamily, 
                                           rtf.SelectionFont.Size, 
                                 rtf.SelectionFont.Style XOr FontStyle.Underline)
```

So the C# equivalent should be something like this:

```
Drawing.Font fnt = new Drawing.Font(rtf.SelectionFont.FontFamily, 
                                    rtf.SelectionFont.Size, 
                                 rtf.SelectionFont.Style ^ FontStyle.Underline);
```

See this question for some background on this: [How to set multiple FontStyles when instantiating a font?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2813134/how-to-set-multiple-fontstyles-when-instantiating-a-font)

Comment: @aelgoa but you have to bear in mind that this code does not deliver exactly the same than yours. It does not account for the condition setting underline/Strikeout. "If(rtf.SelectionFont.Underline, _
  -Drawing.FontStyle.Underline, _
  Drawing.FontStyle.Underline)" is completely ignored.

Comment: @varocarbas No, it's not ignored. `rtf.SelectionFont.Style ^ FontStyle.Underline` will remove the underline flag if it is already set, or add the underline flag if it's not set.

Comment: @大师燈XiHuan this is not what the original code does. The original code sets underline if there is nothing or strikeout if there is underline. Also it mixes up the original style (the bit you contribute with in my answer).

Comment: @大师燈XiHuan actually what the original code does is more complicated= it relies on the integer value of the given styles and adds them up by bringing into account the original style and the aforementioned condition; the actual output from the original VB code is close to random (and thus not even my answer represents an accurate conversion). I have intended to see the true intention rather than what the original code was exactly doing; and in this intention appears -underline (= strikeout)

Comment: uh what it actually did/does is add Underline if its not on else subtract it

Answer (score 2):

The `rtf.SelectionFont.Style +...` bit is wrong. The original VB code should be converted into:

```
Dim fnt As Drawing.Font = New Drawing.Font( _
  rtf.SelectionFont.FontFamily, _
  rtf.SelectionFont.Size, _
  DirectCast(rtf.SelectionFont.Style XOr If(rtf.SelectionFont.Underline, _
  -Drawing.FontStyle.Underline, _
  Drawing.FontStyle.Underline), _
  Drawing.FontStyle) _
)
```

The reason why you get this error when converting directly to C# is that in VB the `FontStyle` accepts a direct translation to integers (note below), with all the rules (+/- signs). In C# you cannot do the same and thus the code above cannot be replicated exactly (the minus part, which actually converts `Underline` into `Strikeout`). Converted C# code:

```
System.Drawing.Font fnt = new System.Drawing.Font(
  rtf_Renamed.SelectionFont.FontFamily, 
  rtf_Renamed.SelectionFont.Size,
  (System.Drawing.FontStyle)(rtf.SelectionFont.Style
    ^ rtf_Renamed.SelectionFont.Underline 
    ? System.Drawing.FontStyle.Strikeout
    : System.Drawing.FontStyle.Underline
  )
);
```

CLARIFICATION

As pointed out via comments, the original VB code performs an implicit conversion (from `FontType` to `Integer`) which shouldn't actually be done. Ideally, both codes should rely on the adequate types and thus on `SelectionFont.Underline` and `FontStyle.Strikeout` or perform the corresponding cast to `Integer`.

NOTE REGARDING FONTSTYLE/ENUMS/CAST/VB

`FontStyle` is an `Enum` of type System.Drawing.FontStyle. The properties of an Enum can be accessed via integer by performing the corresponding cast/conversion (unless having `Option Strict Off` in VB.NET, what is not recommendable). Thus, in theory, the VB version of the OP's code shouldn't even compile with Option Strict On, but it does! This specific configuration (condition inside a DirectCast) seems to be fine, even with Option Strict On! Anecdotic fact with no real influence (you should always cast and rely on Option Strict On) but which it is pretty curious.

Comment: “the FontStyle accepts a direct translation to integers” – with `Option Strict On`? That’d surprise me.

Comment: @KonradRudolph No. But the OP is asking why he can in VB and not in C#; apparently he does not have any problem with VB. But will update this bit too anyway.

Comment: Well his VB code is simply wrong and works only by sheer accident. `Option Strict` is there to pretend this kind of problems and should *always* be assumed `On`, and when it isn’t the code should be assumed broken. I’ve made a habit of rejecting any question which doesn’t comply with that (or, maybe more helpfully, telling OP to fix this part and come back afterwards). However, I appreciate your edit.

Comment: *as far as you cannot mix FontStyles*: That is wrong. Sure you can mix e.g. `Bold` and `Italic`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph thanks to you for your comment. Actually I did test the original code with Option Strict On and works too. FontStyle font = (FontStyle)-Drawing.FontStyle.Underline; does not work in C#; but Dim font As FontStyle = DirectCast(-Drawing.FontStyle.Underline, Drawing.FontStyle) works in VB (Option Stright On). In principle I would expect both situations to have the same behaviour but they don't!

Comment: @大师燈XiHuan before -1 something unmotivatedly, prove your point please. Write down a code where you can set two different styles to the same font by relying on the FontStlye property and I will update my code (build, don't destroy)

Comment: [This enumeration has a FlagsAttribute attribute that allows a bitwise combination of its member values.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.drawing.fontstyle.aspx)

Comment: *Write down a code where you can set two different styles to the same font by relying on the FontStlye property* C#: `var font = FontStyle.Bold ^ FontStyle.Italic;` VB.Net: `Dim font = FontStyle.Bold XOR FontStyle.Italic`

Comment: @大师燈XiHuan you should post the links in English or, if you want to talk with me, in Spanish. Thanks for the code. Next time, put it as a comment and I will update my code accordingly -> build and help, not bothering :)

Comment: @varocarbas sorry for the wrong link. I sometimes forget to change the language: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.drawing.fontstyle.aspx

Comment: @大师燈XiHuan Corrected. The whole point of my answer was highlighting that MattWilco answer was partially wrong (put the original bit just without thinking too much about it); but I am not aggressive like you and didn't -1ed him because his answer included valid bits.

Comment: @varocarbas Sorry, but I think you should stop whining. I don't see your point. Your answer started with a wrong statement, and your code was also wrong. So it was clearly not helpful, and I downvoted it. I was also so kind to leave you a comment explaining what was wrong. Then you corrected it, and I removed my downvote. So where's your problem? I don't see where there was any aggression involved. I think you shouldn't take a downvote personal.

Comment: @varocarbas Yeah, it’s been a long time since I’ve used VB. Now I’m disappointed that Enums implicitly convert to integers with `Option Strict On` but there’s nothing to be done.

Comment: @大师燈XiHuan whining?! I am highlighting how senseles is showing this behaviour (with me or with anyone else); the point of -1s is censuring what is clearly wrong; my answer is not clearly wrong, but had a wrong statement which should have helped to fix. I told you that to contribute to remove this behaviours (downvoting instead contributing positively). Sorry if I chose the wrong word; I honestly don't care if the intention is not bad.

Comment: @KonradRudolph not exactly. Option Strict On does not let you to associated an Enum with an integer but, inside a DirectCast statement, these rules seems to not apply. I have to test this behaviour further to understand its exact implications because haven't ever seen it.

Comment: @varocarbas That sounds like a compiler bug then. In fact, looking at the VB 10 spec, I’m almost certain of that.